# Spark error for python program "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Tags: java, python, apache-spark

I run my `python` kmeans program at spark as below command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://master_ip:7077 my_kmeans.py
```

The main `python` kmeans program seems as below:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
# data
X = jl.load('X.jl.z')
data_x = sc.parallelize(X)
# kmeans
model = KMeans.train(data_x, 10000, maxIterations=5)
```

The file `'X.jl.z'` size is ~100M.

But I get the spark error:

```
  File "/home/xxx/tmp/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/my_kmeans.py", line 24, in <module>
    data_x = sc.parallelize(X)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling    z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.readRDDFromFile.    
  : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I know how to modify JVM heap size for `Java` program. But how can I increase the heap size for my `python` program ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the number of partitions:

```
data_x = sc.parallelize(X,n)
# n = 2-4 partitions for each CPU in your cluster
```

or :

> Maximum heap size settings can be set with spark.driver.memory in the
>   cluster mode and through the --driver-memory command line option in
>   the client mode

Comment: What if it is running on a local computer?